# Reply to sender phpmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I can send emails no problem to my mailbox but the sender is always my own email address and I would like the sender to be the actual email of the person who filled in the contact form, so I can reply directly back.

```
<?php

require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
function SendMail($to, $from, $body, $mail)
{
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
)
);
$mail->isSMTP();

$mail->Host = "smtp.office365.com";
$mail->Port = "587";
$mail->Username = "MY EMAIL ADDRESS HERE";
$mail->Password = "MY PASSWORD";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
// Send the mail

$mail->From = "MY EMAIL ADDRESS HERE";
$mail->setFrom($from, "Contact Form Request");
$mail->AddAddress("MY EMAIL ADDRESS HERE", "Mick");
$mail->Subject = "Contact Form Request";
$mail->Body = $body;

if($mail->send())
{
    return true;
}else{
  var_dump($mail->ErrorInfo);
  die();
  return false;
}

}

if ($_POST["submit"]) {

$userDetails = array(
"sender" => $_POST['name'],
"senderEmail" => $_POST['email'],
"phone"       => $_POST['phone'],
"address1"    => $_POST['address1'],
"address2"    => $_POST['address2'],
"address3"    => $_POST['address3'],
"postcode"    => $_POST['postcode'],
"skipsize"    => $_POST['skipsize'],
"delivery"    => $_POST['delivery'],
"message"     => $_POST['message'],
"pickup"      => $_POST['pickup'],
);


$mailBody .= "Name: $userDetails[sender] \n";
$mailBody .= "Email: $userDetails[senderEmail] \n";
$mailBody .= "Phone Number: $userDetails[phone] \n";
$mailBody .= "Address: $userDetails[address1], $userDetails[address2], $userDetails[address3], $userDetails[$postcode] \n";
$mailBody .= "Phone Number: $userDetails[phone] \n";
$mailBody .= "Skip Size Wanted: $userDetails[skipsize] \n";
$mailBody .= "Delivery Date Wanted: $userDetails[delivery] \n";
$mailBody .= "Pick Up Date Wanted: $userDetails[pickup] \n";
$mailBody .= "Message: $userDetails[message] \n";

if(SendMail("stuart@foamymedia.com", $from, $mailBody, $mail))
{
    $thankYou="<p class='thankyou'>Thank you! Your message has been sent.</p>";

}else{

}

}

?>
```

What am I missing? as it has been bugging me and no answers direct online.

Help would be great

Comment: Have the visitor fill out a form where they input their email address and change it to `$mail->From = $_POST['email'];`? Shouldn't be that hard.. Of course I would validate it first though.

Comment: No, don't do that; It won't work. PHPMailer validates addresses automatically. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really want to do this! It's forgery and will cause SPF checks to fail,  resulting in your messages being bounced or spam filtered.

Do this:

```
$mail->From = "MY EMAIL ADDRESS HERE";
$mail->From = "MY NAME HERE";
if (!$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'])) {
    die('Invalid email address');
}
```

You're using an old version of PHPMailer - [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Also, **do not** disable TLS certificate validation. Office365 **does not** present invalid certificates - if it fails it's caused by some other issue, such as your SMTP traffic being intercepted and redirected by your ISP, which is very common. Find out *why* it's failing and use the sending mechanism your ISP provides - and this may prevent you from using your Office365 address for the same reason you can't forge the from address of your submitters.

All of this is demonstrated in [the contact form example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps).